# QEMU: how to use the virt board

Tags: arm, emulation, qemu, device-tree

I'm trying to play with QEMU, especially with the virt board and device trees, but there isn't much documentation about it.
I managed to emulate a vexpress a9 board and install archlinux on it, mainly thanks to this [link](https://medicineyeh.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/buildup-your-arm-image-for-qemu/), with the following commands:

```
wget http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz
mkdir archlinux_arm_root
bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz -C archlinux_arm_root
qemu-img create -f raw disk_img.img 1G
mkfs.ext4 -F disk_img.img
sudo mkdir /mnt/root
sudo mount -o loop disk_img.img /mnt/root
sudo cp -rf archlinux_arm_root/* /mnt/root/
sudo umount /mnt/root
cp archlinux_arm_root/boot/zImage zImage
cp archlinux_arm_root/boot/dtbs/vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb device_tree.dtb
qemu-system-arm -m 1024M -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -kernel zImage -dtb device_tree.dtb -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw roottype=ext4 console=ttyAMA0" -drive if=sd,driver=raw,cache=writeback,file=disk_img.img -nographic
```

I created a raw disk image, then manually installed archlinux (by mounting the disk image and copying the root file system of arch on it).
The command to emulate the board and boot on arch specifies the `machine/cpu/kernel/device tree/disk image` to use. The `-drive` option defines a new drive, and since it's an SD one I need to tell qemu to use `/dev/mmcblk0` with `-append`. Please correct me if I said anything incorrect.

Firstly I simply want to emulate this machine without using the sd interface, but somehow just can't manage to do so.
But more importantly I'd like to emulate a virt board.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really run the vexpress-a9 board without using the SD interface, because that is the only interface that hardware has for block devices, so your choices are "SD" or "no block device at all".

Our documentation for running Arm guests on QEMU is here https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM and that page links to a tutorial for booting Debian on the 'virt' board for 64-bit guests: https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/installing-debian-on-qemus-64-bit-arm-virt-board/  and one for 32-bit guests: https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2016/11/03/installing-debian-on-qemus-32-bit-arm-virt-board/ so I would start with whichever of those you want.